# Getting the error :No such file or directory while running ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/jenkins_agent_key in a Terminal Window

Tags: jenkins, ssh-keys, openssh, ssh-keygen

I am trying to install a Jenkins agent in a Test machine for Automation and on Generating an SSH key pair,when I hit on  **ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/jenkins_agent_key** in a Terminal Window,I get to enter a Passphase.
Once,I have entered and re-entered the Passphase,I get the error message :
Saving key "~/.ssh/jenkins_agent_key" failed: No such file or directory

I have checked in the Windows 10 machine and it does have the OpenSSH Client and OpenSSH Server installed.

Can anyone please help me to go through why I am getting this error?

Using this Link for reference for Installing the Jenkins Agent : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/

Comment: Where do you execute the `ssh-keygen`? In Windows `cmd.exe`? In Windows `~/` does not exist. That's a Linux thing. Out the key anywhere else, where the Windows Jenkins agent can read it from.

Comment: does folder ~\.ssh really exist? - Maybe you rights are limited, try sudo ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/jenkins_agent_key

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by hitting **ssh-keygen** in the Command Prompt and the Private and Public key did get generated